# Accessibility PDF generation in salesforce

Tags: pdf

We need to generate accessibility PDF for disabled . We are using SDOC which is using salesforce internal PDF generation logic and  unable to create tag required for screen reader . Is there any third party tool which can generate accessibility PDF with specified template

Comment: Have you checked AppExchange?

Comment: Hi David , I have not found any relevant app exchange product for this . We are curretly using SDOC .